# Recommended tips to conduct a workshop

Tags: digital, workshops

Please suggest some good tips on conducting a photography workshop. I am planning to start a basic one first and then will proceed to advanced photography workshops. What tips do you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collected notes after three-day workshop with 11 people in total:

- They divided themselves to two groups based on experience and seemed happy with that.
- It's good to be able to look on pictures everyone took afterwards and talk about them.
- There were positive reaction to shooting together as a group and being able to share knowledge and try out equipment.
- If you have people of various experience, it might be useful to pair more skilled ones with beginners for a while.

Answer (score 2):

I'd first look at other photographers and see what they do, like http://www.kelbytraining.com/ .  The training/workshop topics are pointed to a particular topic, i.e. portraits, where an instructor can discuss the finer points of what goes into portraiture photography.  For a basic topic, maybe you'd want to start out with something like 'basic camera operation'? And more advanced would goto specific shooting style.